Let A, B, and C be sets. Show/prove (Not with venn diagram) that (A-B)-C = (A-C) - (B-C)

I tried to prove this by using logical equivalencies. I attached the picture of my proof. In my proof I stated that (A-B)-C is equal to A and NOT (A and (B or C)) and (A-C) - (B-C) is also equal to A and NOT (A and C) and NOT (B and (B OR C)) which is equal to the first equivalency I found. My professor said my proof is wrong, but when I let A, B and C be sets, I get the correct set. Can anyone explain why I am wrong. Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I can't figure out exactly how to prove this problem in this way right now but I do see that you've written $(B - C) = B \wedge \neg (B \wedge C)$ but right under that line it seems like that has changed to $B \wedge (B \vee C)$. I can't quite follow from there but shouldn't that be $B \wedge (\neg B \vee \neg C)$?

Hello, thanks for answering. The equation under (−)=∧¬(∧) represents the (A-C) - (B-C) equality. During the exam, I noticed that when you have "-" it adds a ¬ in front of the equality and adds an OR like the first equation I found for (A-B)-C just above it. So I didn't distribute ¬ instead wrote another equation for (A-C)-(B-C).

You cannot prove that because it isn't true. Take $A=\{1, 2, 3\}$, $B=\{3, 4, 5\}$, $C=\{2, 3, 5\}$. Then $$A \setminus B = \{1, 2\}, \quad B\setminus C=\{4\},$$
thus
$$(A\setminus B)\setminus C=\{1\} \neq \{1, 2\}=(A\setminus B)\setminus(B\setminus C)$$
EDIT: I originally addressed the question you asked in the title, which does not match the question in the picture. Here's a solution to the problem as it is in the picture.
\begin{align}
&x \in (A \setminus B) \setminus C \quad\mbox{iff} \\
&x \in A \setminus B \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin C\quad\mbox{iff} \\
&x \in A \,\,\wedge \,\, x \notin B\,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin C. 
\end{align}
Now the latter formula is equivalent to
$$(x \in A \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin B \,\,\wedge\,\, x\notin C)\,\,\vee\,\,(x \in A \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin C \,\,\wedge\,\, x \in C),$$ because the formula inside the second pair of brackets is always false. Then we have
\begin{align}
&(x \in A \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin B \,\,\wedge\,\, x\notin C)\,\,\vee\,\,(x \in A \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin C \,\,\wedge\,\, x \in C)\quad\mbox{iff} \\
&x \in A \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin C \,\,\wedge\,\, (x \notin B \,\,\vee\,\, x \in C)\quad\mbox{iff} \\
&x\in A \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin C \,\,\wedge\,\,\neg (x \in B \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin C)\quad\mbox{iff} \\
&x \in A \setminus C \,\,\wedge\,\, x \notin B \setminus C\quad\mbox{iff} \\
&x \in (A \setminus C) \setminus (B\setminus C).
\end{align}

You are absolutely right, the correct formula is $(A\setminus B)\setminus C=(A\setminus \color{red}{\mathbf C})\setminus(B\setminus C),.;$

@Angelo Oh, I see now. I addressed the question in the title, but the picture asks to prove a different thing, which corresponds to your correction.

Apologies for the mistake in the title—I’m still getting the hang of this platform.

Also, you could prove that $(A\setminus B)\setminus C=A\setminus(B\cup C)$ and $(A\setminus B)\setminus C=(A\setminus C)\setminus B,.;$

@SametCimen I'll edit the post with a correct solution of the question as it is in the picture.

Thank you for sharing the edited solution—I see where I went wrong now. I really appreciate your help, especially during this busy midterm season. It means a lot. Thanks again

I assume here that what you want to prove is $(A\setminus B)\setminus C = (A\setminus B)\setminus(B\setminus C)$, because your proposal is wrong.
It becomes easy as soon as you go back to the definition (by the elements of the sets) of the difference of two sets: $A\setminus B = \{x\in A\mid x\notin B\}$ or $x\in A\setminus B\iff x\in A\land x\notin B$.
Note: I shall use here the following notations: $A$ minus $B$ is $A\setminus B$, $\land$ is a logical and, $\lor$ is a logical or, $\lnot$ is a logical not.
So we can write:
$$\begin{align}
x\in (A\setminus B)\setminus C&\iff x\in (A\setminus B)\land x\notin C\iff(x\in A \land x\notin B)\land x\notin C\\&\iff x\in A\land x\notin B \land x\notin C
\end{align}$$
On the other hand:
$$\begin{align}
x\in(A\setminus B)\setminus(B\setminus C)&\iff x\in(A\setminus B)\land x\notin(C\setminus B)\\
&\iff (x\in A\land x\notin B)\land\lnot(x\in C\land x\notin B)\\&\iff
(x\in A\land x\notin B)\land(x\notin C\lor x\in B)\\&\iff
(x\in A\land x\notin B\land x\notin C)\lor(x\in A\land x\notin B\land c\in B)\\&\iff
(x\in A\land x\notin B\land x\notin C)\lor FALSE\\&\iff x\in A\land x\notin B\land x\notin C
\end{align}$$
